# Best way to track email views?

Tags: image, email, tracking

I will be developing something that will interface with Asterisk to mark voicemail as read when a user opens the email notification (I realize IMAP fits this bill perfectly, unfortunately, it's not what we're looking for...).  My thought was to embed an image in the email that is named uniquely to that voicemail; once I see that the image was viewed in apache logs, then mark it as read.  I have to believe this has been developed already (perform action when image is viewed), but I'm not sure what to be looking for.  Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing, and can you share what you used/any tips you might have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any server-side language:

```
hostname.com/voicemailread?id=....
```

That page should output an image (with the correct `Content-Type`) and update a db record.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that's how best to do it, my question is on the actual _doing_ of it;

Comment: The actual doing depends on which server-side language and environment you're using, which you left out.